# Display big image from SD card in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, mediastore, out-of-memory

In Android, how do you display an image (**of any size**) from the SD card, **without getting an out of memory error**?

Is it necessary to put the image in the Media Store first?

A pseudo-code example would be greatly appreciated. **Extra points if the displayed image is as big as the memory level of the device allows**.

Comment: try following that Google recommended: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit: this question has actually been already answered at [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue) (the two highest voted answers). It does also use the `inSampleSize` option, but with a small method to automatically get the appropriate value.**

My original answer:

The `inSampleSize` of the `BitmapFactory.Options` class can solve your issue (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize). It works by making a bitmap with the resulting width and height 1/`inSampleSize` than the original, thus reducing memory consumption (by `inSampleSize`^2?). You should read the doc before using it.

Example:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
// will results in a much smaller image than the original
options.inSampleSize = 8;

// don't ever use a path to /sdcard like this, but I'm sure you have a sane way to do that
// in this case nebulae.jpg is a 19MB 8000x3874px image
final Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/nebulae.jpg", options);

final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_id);
iv.setImageBitmap(b);
Log.d("ExampleImage", "decoded bitmap dimensions:" + b.getWidth() + "x" + b.getHeight()); // 1000x485
```

However here it will only work for images up to, I guess, `inSampleSize`^2 times the size of the allowed memory and will reduce the quality of small images.
The trick would be to find the appropriate inSampleSize.

Comment: Thanks Gautier. The two highest rated answers of your link use a constant to determine the maximum size of the image. Is there a way to determine this value based on the memory level of the device?

Comment: Yes indeed, but you'll probably use the image for an ImageView with limited dimension, and if your image is bigger than this you will just waste (valuable!) memory.

Answer (score 4):

I'm displaying any sized images using code:

```
ImageView imageView=new ImageView(this);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize=2; //try to decrease decoded image
options.inPurgeable=true; //if necessary purge pixels into disk
options.inScaled=true; //scale down image to actual device density
Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
fis.close();
```

Comment: This is working fine but still giving OutOfMemory error sometimes. The error ration is 1 out of 15 trials. So can you please suggest an additional configuration needed to avoid that 1 error. I mean to make it 100% workable.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
yourImgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/1.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.developer.com/ws/other/article.php/3748281/Working-with-Images-in-Googles-Android.htm covers all you'll ever need to know on the subject of images, including getting them from an SD card. You'll notice the code to do so there, copied below:

```
try {
   FileOutputStream fos = super.openFileOutput("output.jpg",
      MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

   mBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);

   fos.flush();
   fos.close();
   } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e("MyLog", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: And that article is far from everything you need to know to deal with images on Android.

Comment: Okay, you make some good points... But it does answer the question asked... Perhaps another question on how to load an image that is larger then the available memory could be asked?

Comment: The question specifically states the memory issue, but I clarified the title just in case.